# Having sub-projects within a sonarqube project

Tags: sonarqube

I have CI setup with a few C# applications for service fabric.

I'm running the SonarQube scanner on a few projects with my CI tool, but I would like the data to be aggregated into one project in SonarQube, and have it separated by sub-folder/"component". However when I try to push results to one project, it just wipes out all the previous history of the past project.

For example I want my single sonarqube project to look like:
SonarQubeProject
-- serviceProject1
-- serviceProject2

where project1 & project 2 are analyzed separately. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe [Project Tags](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Project+Settings#ProjectSettings-Tags) can help you. It is important to mention the SonarQube version you use. In money is no problem you could have a look at the [Governance Plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Governance+Plugin).

Comment: @JeroenHeier , We're using version 6.1. I'm not able to see how you can specify a project tag? It seems to be lacking from the documentation. We have projects but there's a way to tag certain code within a single project?

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube 6.7 will introduce the [concept of "Application"s](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-938) as a paid feature (part of the "governance" plugin). This feature will allow the user to group several SonarQube projects into a bigger application.

Comment: My company is on version 6.1 so unfortunately we don't have that.

Comment: @DaveN That version is not released yet. To get the [Governance plugin](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance.html) you have to join the (costly) Enterprise Plan.